# My string index keeps getting out of range in Python3

Tags: python, vigenere

Im coding in python and working towards encrypting with the Vigenere method.
Im using Python 3.6.2. and Visual Studio Code

```
import sys

def hi():
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        exit

keyword = sys.argv[1]
index = 0
shift = 0
keylength = len(sys.argv[1])

if str.isalpha(keyword):
    plaintext = input("plaintext:")
    print("ciphertext:", end='')

for i in range(0,keylength):
    if str.isalpha(plaintext):
        index = i % keylength

        if (str.isupper(plaintext[i])):
            print(keyword[index-65])

        elif (str.islower(plaintext[i])):
            shift = keyword[index-97]
    print(shift)
```

So this is my code but I get this error:

```
File "vigenere.py", line 22, in <module>
print(ord(keyword[index-65]))
IndexError: string index out of range
```

So the shift is not working. How could I fix?

Comment: Well if `index` is something small like 0, then you're trying to access `keyword[-65]`. What string are you trying this with?

Comment: You have lots of problems in this code. You should be looping over the indexes of the characters in `plaintext`, not `keylength`. You need to get the character codes of the current element in `keyword` and `plaintext`, and do your calculations on those.

Comment: The function `ord(character)` will return the characer code.

Comment: At a risk of being nitpicky: your traceback snippet is not from the code shown. There's no `ord()` call, and that actually matters since it looks like you're trying to twiddle with the codepoints, but misplaced the subtraction

Comment: That's a lot of help Ilja. Thank you. Lets have a look